# Using Ionicons in Ionic 2

Tags: icons, ionic2, ionicons

How can i use [Ionicons](http://ionicons.com/cheatsheet.html) in **`Ionic 2`** , i've following [this tutorial](http://tphangout.com/using-ionicons-in-ionic-2) but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to import anything to use them. Just find the name of the one you need [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/ionicons/) and then use that name to include it in your view:

```
  <!--Basic: auto-select the icon based on the platform -->
  <ion-icon name="american-football"></ion-icon>

  <!-- Advanced: explicity set the icon for each platform -->
  <ion-icon ios="ios-american-football" md="md-american-football"></ion-icon>
```

Comment: ok thank you but some icons is missing i've use `facebook` icon but it's **squared** so i want to use another icons, any suggestions ?

Comment: Hmm... you can add font-awesome or any other set of icons in order to use a different icon for facebook.